# jQuery fadeIn function in PrototypeJS

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am new to Prototype. How can I write the following jQuery code in Prototype? 
Thanks in advance..

```
$('#lessonid').fadeIn(function(){
   $('.exercise').css('margin-bottom', '0px');        
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the PrototypeJS library doesn't have any animation/effects methods built in. You can use [Scriptaculous](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/), which is an add-on to Prototype. That will allow you to do something like this, using the [`fade`](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-fade/) method:

```
$('lessonid').fade({
    from: 0, 
    to: 1,
    afterFinish: function() {
        $$('.exercise').setStyle({
            marginBottom: 0
        });
    }
});
```