# running ajax code after fade function is completed

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I need to run my ajax function after fade is completed. How can I do that? Thanks.

```
$$('.loading').invoke("fade", "from: 0, to: 1");

new Ajax.Request(ajaxUrl,
    {
     method:'post',
     onSuccess: function(data){
     var tmp=data.responseText;
     $$('.content').invoke('insert',tmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since the `fade` method expects an object as an argument, you need to pass an object to `invoke` instead of a string. Then, you can add the `afterFinish` property to that object (as I already showed you how to do in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815334/jquery-fadein-function-in-prototypejs)):

```
$$('.loading').invoke("fade", {
    from: 0, 
    to: 1,
    afterFinish: function() {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

However, note that since `invoke` basically iterates over the array of elements, the `afterFinish` callback will be called once for every element. I don't know if you want to fire multiple AJAX requests or not, but it's worth bearing that in mind.